# Naming pandas columns with variables

Tags: pandas

I have a list of tuples, which has all possible combinations of a dataframe's columns. I'd like to create new dataframe columns by combining these columns' values.

Example dataframe

```
d = {'c1':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c2':['Low', 'Low', 'High'], 'c3':['True', 'True', 'False']}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

All possible columns combinations with length 2

```
from itertools import combinations 
com = list(combinations(dd.columns, 2))
```

It returns`[('c1', 'c2'), ('c1', 'c3'), ('c2', 'c3')]`

I'd like to create new columns with the above combinations

For example, creating a combined column
`dd['c1 + c2'] = dd['c1'] + '+' + dd['c2']`

```
    c1  c2      c1 + c2
0   a   Low     a+Low
1   b   Low     b+Low
2   c   High    c+High
```

The real dataframe has many columns so I would like to automate the process by looping through the tuple list and use variables as dataframe's new column names.

Something like this:

```
[dd[f'dd[i[0]] + dd[i[1]]'] = dd[i[0]] + '+' + dd[i[1]] for i in com]
```

where `dd[i[0]]` = 'c1' and `dd[i[1]]` = 'c2'

I'm pretty sure I cannot use f-strings in dataframe columns but don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Similar to something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135669/generating-all-the-combinations-of-7-columns-in-a-dataframe-and-add-the-correspo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
for i in com:
    dd[f'{i[0]} + {i[1]}']= dd[i[0]] + '+' + dd[i[1]]
```

Comment: The new column name will become "i[0] + i[1]" but I want the column name as "c1 + c2"